# HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>(); for pass image

Tags: android

```
for(int i=0;i<StoreparsrData.title.size();i++){
        HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Bitmap bt=Utility.getBitmapFile(StoreparsrData.url.get(i).toString());
         ImageView img=(ImageView)findviewbyid(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(bt);
```

but iwant to convert this `img.setImageBitmap(bt);` to string so its input for

```
temp.put("image",image );




    temp.put("title",StoreparsrData.title.get(i).toString());
    temp.put("description", StoreparsrData.description.get(i).toString());
    temp.put("lastbuilddate", StoreparsrData.lastBuildDate.get(0).toString());
    list.add(temp);
    }
```

so its show image 
Pls Reply me

Comment: Have you consider editing your post to bring it to some understandable level?

Comment: Your code is poorly formatted and doesn't compile, and I don't really understand the question.  Perhaps you can edit the question to be a little more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, why not use:

```
temp.put("image",StoreparsrData.url.get(i).toString());
```

Then perform the `ImageView` lookup when you read from the `list`

**EDIT**

Here's another approach:

```
public class ParseBean {
    private ImageView image;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String lastBuildDate;
    // add getters and setters here
}
...
for(int i=0;i<StoreparsrData.title.size();i++){
    HashMap<String,ParseBean> temp = new HashMap<String,ParseBean>();
    Bitmap bt=Utility.getBitmapFile(StoreparsrData.url.get(i).toString());
    ImageView img=(ImageView)findviewbyid(R.id.img);
    img.setImageBitmap(bt);
    ParseBean bean = new ParseBean();
    bean.setImage(img);
    bean.setTitle(StoreparsrData.title.get(i).toString());
    bean.setDescription(StoreparsrData.description.get(i).toString());
    bean.setLastBuildDate(StoreparsrData.lastBuildDate.get(0).toString());
    list.add(bean);
}
```

Comment: But in this StoreparseData.url.get(i).toString() Here Storeparsedata  is the class & url is a vector. Parsed data r stored in this vector.In parsed data only this give url like www.fifa.com/fifa.gif so we cant directly show this link  so take another class Utility.class that convert this link to image       its code this like  Bitmap bt=Utility.getBitmapFile(StoreparsrData.url.get(i).toString());
         ImageView img=(ImageView)findviewbyid(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(bt);                                      & now i want to pass this img so pls help me

Comment: added an alternative approach